# Must a non-well-founded model of Z contain a countable collection that looks like a proper class to the model?

Tags: set-theory, nonstandard-models

Let's say we have a (not transitive) model, $(M,E)$, of Z. In this post, "class" means an arbitrary collection of elements of $M$. Let $x_0\ni x_1\ni x_2\ni\cdots$ be an infinite descending chain of elements of $M$. Then $X=\{x_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is countable (outside of $M$), but $X$ cannot be a set in $M$ since it violates Foundation. Hence, $M$ sees $X$ as a proper class.

Anything wrong with this reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your use of "class" here is a bit odd. Usually a class is required to be definable in some sense, and $X$ is definitely not. Indeed, re: your last sentence I would say that $M$ doesn't "see" $X$ in any sense whatsoever.

However, if you simply use "proper class in the sense of $M$" to refer to any subset of $M$ which is not in $M$ (or, more accurately, is not of the form $\{b\in M: b\in^Ma\}$ for some $a\in M$), then yes, $X$ is a proper class in the sense of $M$.

Comment: I take your point. I don't know a better term for "subset $M$ that is not of the form $\{b\in M:b\in^M a\}$ for some $a\in M$". I feel like even using "subset" can be confusing, since a subset sounds like it should be a set, which would be an element of $M$. "Arbitrary subcollection" maybe?

Comment: But is there a formula $F$ with one free variable such that $(\exists x\,(F(x))^{(M,E)}$ and $(\neg \exists y \,\forall x\,(F(x)\implies x\in y))^{(M,E)}$ and such that $\{x\in M: (F(x)^{(M,E)}\}$ is countable?

Comment: @Noah Schweber  I looked at your profile and see that you are a former academic who is still interested in doing research as a hobby. I'm in the same boat, and I've been wanting to try to organize something online (possible through this site) to help people in this situation find each other and collaborate on research. Basically, a support group for math researchers outside academia. If this idea is interesting to you, I'm planning to make a post called "Research Collaboration Outside Academia".

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Not necessarily. If the ordinals of $M$ have uncountable cofinality, then if $X\subseteq M$ is countable it is a subcollection of $(V_\alpha)^M$ for some $M$-ordinal $\alpha$. If $X$ is definable in $M$, this means $X$ is also a set in $M$ (via separation).